# changing the format of date in listview c#

Tags: c#, date, listview

how can i change the format of date in the windows form listview? I am getting the dates from the database and the date format is MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss. I want to display the format MM/dd/yyyy. PLease help me.

`

```
        Class1.reader = Class1.dbcommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (Class1.reader.Read())
        {

            lstitem = listView1.Items.Add(Class1.reader[0].ToString());
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(Class1.reader[1].ToString());
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(Class1.reader[2].ToString());
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(Class1.reader[3].ToString());
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(Class1.reader[4].ToString());
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(Class1.reader[5].ToString());
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(Class1.reader[6].ToString());
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(Class1.reader[7].ToString());
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(Class1.reader[8].ToString());
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(Class1.reader[9].ToString());
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(Class1.reader[10].ToString());
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(Class1.reader[11].ToString());
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(Class1.reader[12].ToString());
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(Class1.reader[13].ToString());
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(Class1.reader[14].ToString());
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(Class1.reader[15].ToString());
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(Class1.reader[16].ToString());
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(Class1.reader[17].ToString());
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(Class1.reader[18].ToString());
            lstitem.SubItems.Add(Class1.reader[19].ToString());
        }`
```

(this is how I am getting the data from the database)

Comment: How do you keep them in your database exactly? As a `DateTime` or as a `string`? Can you please show your work as well?

Comment: Actually the data type that I used is date and I am using sql server 2008 r2. I don't why it is displaying the format MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Comment: Show your display code as well so we can help you.

Comment: @SonerGönül I've posted my code in displaying the data.

Comment: Which of these is the `DateTime` you are referring to? Using `reader` as a variable name and a number as an index for SQL data is generally frowned upon. From the looks of it, we cannot tell *which field* is the actual `DateTime`. Regardless, you should add the following inside the `.ToString()` method for whichever field is a `DateTime`: `"MM/dd/yyyy"`.

Comment: @EBrown there's an error, No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: You will likely need to *cast* the object first.

Comment: @EBrown, btw, I am referring to lstitem.SubItems.Add(Class1.reader[7].ToString()); as the DateTime..

Comment: Try **casting** it (hint, to cast an object: `(DateTime)variable`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lstitem.SubItems.Add(DateTime.Parse(Class1.reader[1].ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

Try That

Comment: there's an error, No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments.

Comment: how about if my data type in the database is varchar?

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime to convert the date in your prefered format:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: @SonerGönül I don't know, I'm new to StackOverflow. But his question is pretty generic and lacks detailed information, so pointing him in the right direction seemd like the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply :

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy");
```

[You can get more info about datetime formats here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("12/02/21 10:56:09", "yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    ).ToString("MMM. dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```